# load selective css using jquery by querying width and height of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am currently using this script to load the correct CSS depending on the screen width. It works fine. However I have issues when trying to load the correct script by querying both width and height. The script is as below. Can someone correct me where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    height = $(window).height();
    if (width < 1010) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1024.css");
    } else if ((width < 1281) && (height > 780)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1280.css");
    } else if ((width < 1281) && (height < 800)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1280mac.css");
    } else if (width < 1370) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1366.css");
    } else if (width < 1450) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_mac1.css");
    } else if (width < 1610) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1600.css");   
    } else {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_FHD.css"); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width());
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not use CSS media queries? They were designed for exactly this purpose and have the added benefit of not relying on JS, so you don't get a FOUC, nor would it break if someone has JS turned off.

Comment: Hi Rory. well the reason why i didnt use media queries is that i had issues using that to load multiple css. i had used it in the beginning when the website just needed 2 different css.

Answer (score 0):

**You are passing `width` parameter to your function but not `height` so this problem is coming.**

> I have edited the code, hope it works!!

```
function adjustStyle(width, height) {
    width = parseInt(width);
    height = parseInt(height);
    if (width < 1010) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1024.css");
    } else if ((width < 1281) && (height > 780)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1280.css");
    } else if ((width < 1281) && (height < 800)) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1280mac.css");
    } else if (width < 1370) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1366.css");
    } else if (width < 1450) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_mac1.css");
    } else if (width < 1610) {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_1600.css");   
    } else {
        $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "css/style_FHD.css"); 
    }
}

$(function() {
    adjustStyle($(this).width(), $(this).height());
    $(window).resize(function() {
        adjustStyle($(this).width(), $(this).height());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way. The code given below is working....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>question1</title>
<link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style3.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>


$(window).ready(function(){


if($(window).width()<1281 && $(window).height()>780)
{
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href","style1.css");
}
else if($(window).width()<1281 && $(window).height()<800)
{
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href","style2.css");
}
else
{
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href","style3.css");
}       


});


$( window ).resize(function() {



if($(window).width()<1281 && $(window).height()>780)
{
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href","style1.css");
}
else if($(window).width()<1281 && $(window).height()<800)
{
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href","style2.css");
}
else
{
    $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href","style3.css");
}
});

</script>

<body>
<div>
this is a webpage
</div>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: hi saif. i tried using your code but it still loads the first css of the script where height is involved. when i resize the height of the browser, it still picks up the first scripts css.for example the one with the 780 as height. even when i resize the browser, it ignores the 800 one